# Android: where is View.getOnTouchListener()?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I would like to implement a generic system that overrides all the onTouchListener
on a viewGroup and restore them later.

I tought about map to store each view's original listeners but I did not find any way to
get the currently assigned  listener.

I need to do something like this:

```
View v;
View.onTouchListener backupListener = v.getOnTouchListener();
```

But unfortunately getOnTouchListener does not exists ? How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use setOnTouchListener it's not overriding the touch Listener but just saving a pointer to another touch listener, so you can actually call to the original touch Listener:

```
view =  findViewById(R.id.someView);
    //alternative:
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("touch"," alternative");
            return true;
        }
    });
    //call to the original:
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return v.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

you can check out the source code of setOnTouchListener();

Comment: @Julien: have you tried this? can you accept the answer

Comment: I am looking at the source code, and this seems to be patently incorrect... where do you see that?

Comment: @Oded: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29. goto line 4898 (this is the implementation). pay attention that in my example I've called to "onTouchEvent" and not "onTouch"

Comment: The code you link to is what I saw. It's not adding an additional listener--it's replacing any existing one. Take a look at line 4647 for addOnLayoutChangeListener()... *that* adds another one. There can only be one touch listener.